# Last 10 weeks in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using a Procedure that returns the turnover of the stores by weeks:
https://i.ibb.co/N3sP2Jp/1.png

[image]

I want just the last 10 weeks, from current week.
And the same for the previous year.

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(WEEK, [GP_DATEPIECE]) AS [WEEK],
    [et_libelle] AS [STORE NAME],
     SUM(TOTALTTC) AS [TU],
     SUM(TOTALTTC) AS [TU -1],

GROUP BY
    [et_libelle],
    DATENAME(WEEK, [GP_DATEPIECE])
```

Comment: How is week defined?

Comment: From monday to Sunday

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWER THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

To get the last 10 weeks *in the data*, you can do:

```
where datepiece >= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()) - 10, 0)
```

Comment: Thank u that's work, but i want also last 10 weeks for previous year

Comment: Should i post new question ?

Comment: @hamza.soufiane . . . Yes.  That would be the appropriate course of action.  Changing questions that have already been answered can invalidate the answers, leading to downvotes.  In addition, it can start down an unending path of edit/answer.  Some changes are, of course, warranted an useful, but I'm very sensitive to changes in scope.

Comment: Thank's so much, i posted a new question, i hope u can help

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the script as per your requirement and I hope we are now so close to your requirement now. The output from the below query is a raw rows for your data comparison. You can now apply aggregation on your result set by applying GROUP by on YR (for whole years data comparison) and even you can add WK number in GROUP by so that you can compare data between Year and Week wise.

Note: As I applied ISO_Week, Week Starts at Monday and Ends at Sunday.

```
WITH CTE (COMMON,DayMinus)
AS
(
SELECT 1,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,5 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,6 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,7 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,8 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,9
)
SELECT YEAR(your_date_column) YR,
DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, your_date_column) WK,
* 
FROM your_table
WHERE YEAR(your_date_column) IN (2019,2018)
AND DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, your_date_column) IN
(
    SELECT A.WKNUM-CTE.DayMinus AS [WEEK NUMBER] 
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 1 AS COMMON,DATENAME(ISO_WEEK,GETDATE()) WKNUM
    ) A ON CTE.COMMON = A.COMMON
)
```

Comment: I want to compare value of this week with week of previous year

Comment: You mean compare data from same week from different year?

Comment: Yes, for ex : I want to compare data between : 10 last week of 2019 with last 10 week of 2018

Comment: You mean data from Week 10 to 19, 2019 compare with data from Week 10 to 19, 2018.... Right?

Comment: Exactly. in condition the week must start with Monday and End in Sunday

Comment: Yes, that means ISOWEEK. Let me check I can establish the logic or not.

Comment: Please check the updated script and the changed description as well.

Comment: I want 2 columns : One for data of 2019, and another for data of 2018

Comment: 2018 (for all 10 weeks) and 2019 (for all 10 weeks)... Right?